# Natural Sorting in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

```
 SortedList = List.OrderBy(object1=> object1.Order.Split(';')[0])
                        .ThenBy(object2=> object2.Order.Split(';')[1])
                        .ThenBy(object3=> object3.Order.Split(';')[2])
                        .ToList();
```

Order has a Value off 1;1;1. I Split at ";" and sort the Elements. But i get a "alphabetical Order". That means 1,10,2,3. String Format to 4 Digits is not possible because the object is not a String. Is a natural Order possible in LINQ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You could Select() to tuple (obj, int s0, int s1, int s2) and then order by the ints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you certain that every `Object.Order` is a colon separated string of at least 3 integer values?

Why not convert these three values to integer and sort by the parsed values?

```
var result = myInputSequence.Select(sourceItem => new
{

    SplitOrderNumbers = (sourceItem.Order.Split(';')
        .Select(splitItem => Int32.Parse(splitItem))
        .Take(3)
        .ToList(),
    OriginalSourceItem = sourceItem,
})
.OrderBy(item => item.SplitOrderNumbers[0])
.ThenBy(item => item.SplitOrderNumbers[1])
.ThenBy(item => item.SplitOrderNumbers[2])
.Select(item => item.OriginalSourceItem);
```

Bonus point: unlike in your solution, you split your orders only once.

Comment: I was about to post this minus the single split. I humbly retract and upvote for your better answer.

Comment: Technically speaking I think the underlying quicksort algorithm is gonna re-issue those split operations

Answer (score 0):

You can customize ordering behavior to your needs by implementing IComparer.    See: [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___1__).  That said, I like Harald Coppoolse's answer better.  In fact, I like his answer so much I like it in linq syntax too:

```
var result = from n in myInputSequence
                let split = n.Order.Split(';').
                    Select(splitItem => Int32.Parse(splitItem)).
                    Take(3).ToList()
                orderby split[0], split[1], split[2]
                select n;
```